# Octave operator -: automatic broadcasting operation applied

Tags: ubuntu, matrix, operators, octave

In octave 3.6.2, I have a matrix `X=[1 2 3; 2 4 5; 2 6 5; 2 3 7; 3 6 8; 2 4 6; 3 6 8; 4 7 10]` and I want to calculate X-mean(X), which gives me:

```
octave:2> X-mean(X)
warning: operator -: automatic broadcasting operation applied
ans =

  -1.37500  -2.75000  -3.50000
  -0.37500  -0.75000  -1.50000
  -0.37500   1.25000  -1.50000
  -0.37500  -1.75000   0.50000
   0.62500   1.25000   1.50000
  -0.37500  -0.75000  -0.50000
   0.62500   1.25000   1.50000
   1.62500   2.25000   3.50000
```

however, when I try the same command on a different machine, it complains that the sizes of matrices do not match:

```
error: operator -: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 7x3, op2 is 1x3)
```

Any idea how to activate that "**automatic broadcasting operation**" which is applied in the first case? (octave versions are the same!)

Comment: that seems very weird. You can't activate or deactivate automatic brodcasting. Are you sure they really are running the same Octave version? Note that you may have the same Octave version installed on both machine but running different versions. Check the value of `OCTAVE_VERSION` at the octave prompt.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can explicitly request broadcasting by calling `bsxfun(operation, A, B)`, so in your case:

```
bsxfun(@minus, X, mean(X))
```

[Octave reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html), [Matlab reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

Answer (score 6):

sorry to come in so late.
Although with the same version, you are likely to have the 2nd machine setup different.

Look at [Octave Broadcasting documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html), you can set the warning beahaviour directly:

`warning ("error", "Octave:broadcast");`

vs.

```
warning ("off", "Octave:broadcast");
```